# Align content of cell in TableLayout to the right

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to android development. I have an activity with a TableLayout. The activity is built like in the image below.

[image: Activity]

I want the two smaller buttons to be on the right, so that both EditTexts can use the full remaining width. I also tried to set "android:gravity" like some posts suggested, but without any effects. How do I get that done?

Additionally, I have 2 tableRows for the both lines with the info, text & button.
The rest of the activity is out of any tableRow to get them full-width.
Is that common-use or bad programming? If so, how is the better way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strInputInfo"
        android:id="@+id/lblHexToRGB"
        android:layout_column="1" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtHexInput"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:hint="@string/strHexInputHint" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/strConvertButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/cmdConvertCode"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/strRGBInfo"
            android:id="@+id/lblRGBInfo"
            android:layout_column="0" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="350px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtOutputRGB"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/strButtonCopyText"
        android:id="@+id/cmdCopyRGBToClipboard"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strHexInfo"
        android:id="@+id/lblHexInfo"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutputHex"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/strButtonCopyText"
        android:id="@+id/cmdCopyHexToClipboard"
        android:layout_column="2"/>
</TableRow>


<ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp" />
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TableRow layout is exactly like a LinearLayout (in fact, it's a subclass of LinearLayout), so you can use the layout_weight property from LinearLayout to allow a view in a row to expand to fill space in relation to the other views in its row.

For example, your EditText could be:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutputRGB"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

Note that the width is 0 and the weight is 1. When the other views in the row have a weight of 0 (the default) This tells TableRow to allocate as much space as it can to the EditText while the other views get the minimal amount of space required to render.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the tablerow to fill_parent and then you can use  **android:layout_gravity="right"**

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strHexInfo"
        android:id="@+id/lblHexInfo"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutputHex"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/strButtonCopyText"
        android:id="@+id/cmdCopyHexToClipboard"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_column="2"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: @Marcel yes I see that you mentioned that however you currently have your TableRow layout_width set to fill_parent. I am suggesting changing this as well or you can try Doug_Stevenson's option which is a good solution as well .